# C# naming convention for initialized variable - are there special cases?

Tags: c#, .net, naming-conventions

I've spent some time on recapitulating on my knowledge about naming conventions in C# then look over my code and the code of some colleagues with at least 3-4 years experience and I'm not sure if they just are used to incorrect conventions or I'm not informed for some certain cases.

From what I see, when we declare variable no matter if it's initialized or not the name should be in Pascal case (no constants here) but I see this snippet in a code of my colleague with a lot more experience than me :

```
WebImage UploadImage = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();
```

So here `UploadImage` begins with upper case. Are there special cases (again not declaring constants) when this style is accepted or it's just my college not following the common naming convention?

P.S

Due to the many responses that conventions at the end are decided by the team (which I also agree is correct) I want to say that we are several people but not much of a team so I want to follow some general convention and I thought it's understood that I mean `msdn recommendations` but I see that it's not that clear at all so this P.S. is to clear this topic. We are generally not following any team convention, but I don't want this to stop me from adopting some widely used convention and I think that what msdn recommend is a good place to start since it's all up to me to decide.

Thanks to all that answered!

Comment: Conventions are not "correct" or "not correct". They are just that - conventions. You use what the project/team agree on - an incorrect usage would be when the agreed on convention are not followed is all.

Comment: Why would you have different names for initialised vs uninitialised variables in C#? Variables are mutable so they can change between the two, and surely they'll need to be initialised at some point if they're going to be any use?
Or am I confused?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft has [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for most identifiers, but private variables are not included in those.

The most common convention is to use camel case for local variables:

```
WebImage uploadImage = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();
```

There is no common convention for naming variables differently depending on whether they are initialised when they are declared or not. An uninitialised variable would eventually get initialised, making the naming confusing. Also, there is generally no need to single out uninitialised variables, as the compiler won't let you read a variable that is not known to definitely have been assigned.

Answer (score 1):

There is no one set of naming conventions - you need to pick one to adopt.  I've never seen any which differ for an initialised variable, but commonly a locally declared variable won't start with a capital - those are left for class-level properties.

The conventions I use are from the [IDesign C# Coding Standards](http://www.idesign.net/Downloads/GetDownload/1985)

Answer (score 0):

Local variables should be in camelCase according to Microsoft.

For member variables there is different styles (as it's not officially specified) being the one I prefer to prefix with _ e.g: _upperImage. This way you can easily identify a member variable.

Also as mentioned by the above answer consistancy is more important than conventions. If all the rest of the code is in a certain style that style should be followed (or all changed)

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, a conventions correctness is only as valid as the team decides. There are a multitude of conventions with no ***correct*** one.

I recommend that you choose the easiest conventions for your team to follow. Static analysis tools help me abide by conventions, and I would start there. Have your team research and try different tools and use the best one you find. Then let the tool do the grunt work.

I personally have found [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) to be useful. According to [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/), your code should look like this:

```
WebImage uploadImage = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();
```